# Broken snap core module

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

All my snaps were deleted by mistake. 
After that all my apps are not working any more. After investigation using `snap list` command, I found that all my snaps are broken
[image]

I fixed all snaps using

`sudo snap remove [PACKAGE]`

then

```
sudo snap install [PACKAGE]
```

Unfortunately I could not fix the core broken module. All my snaps still not working. Any ideas!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, After 6 hours work. I fixed it using:

```
snap refresh core --edge
snap refresh core18 --edge
```

Comment: Switching to an `edge` channel is not exactly what you'd want. You might want to consider switching back to `stable` after this command. In my case I've resolved a similar issue by removing and installing a snap back.

Comment: Wasn't it replaced with flatpak now?

Answer (score -1):

One-liner that fixes all broken packages. It first updates them to
edge and then downgrades them back to stable.

```
snap list |grep broken |cut -d " " -f 1 |xargs -I {} snap refresh {} --edge
snap list |cut -d " " -f 1 |xargs -I {} snap refresh {} --stable
```

Sometimes this doesn't work. Another approach is just to remove the broken snap and then to reinstall:

```
snap remove packagename
snap install packagename
```